# In TestCafe Studio: Is there a way to execute the steps of a previous test?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My test include steps which need to be repeated for every test.

Tests are something like this:

1. Open Login Dialog (click login button)
2. Login (enter username and password)
3. Navigate to private page (click menu point)

Each of the tests depends on the previous tests.

Id like to use a function like "execute previous test code" which when called within test 3, call test 2 and therefore test 1. It is also important that hooks are not executed at this point.

For hand-written tests, this is not an issue: I'd define the tests as seperate functions and call them accordingly, instead of defining then as anonymous function within the test() call.

For TestCafe Studio I felt "hacky" calling internal APIs and created this function:

```js
function executePreviousTestCode(t) {
    const id = t.testRun.test.id;
    const tests = t.testRun.test.testFile.collectedTests;
    const prevTestIndex = tests.findIndex(t => t.id === id) -1;
    if(prevTestIndex < 0) return;
    const prevTest = tests[prevTestIndex];
    return prevTest.fn(t)
}
```

It works for normal TestCafe but I dont know how to include it in a TestCafe Studio test.

Maybe someone came up with a better solution than copy&paste or one single big test.

Answer (score 2):

In TestCafe you can use [User Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html#user-roles) and/or [beforeEach hooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/organize-tests.html#initialization-and-clean-up) for authorization purposes.
The `beforeEach` hook allows you to run code before each test in a fixture and `User Roles` allows you to define multiple login routines and use them on demand.

TestCafe Studio does not support `User Roles` for recorded tests. However, you can convert your recorded test to a script and apply `User Roles` there.

Comment: We are evaluating TestCafe Studio at the moment. For me as a developer I would not use Studio because I feel very comfortable writing JS Code.
But I will not be the one who writes tests. My colleagues in the Support department will - an they have little to no coding knowledge.
Therefore the only thing that seems acceptible to me is some boilerplate code I can automatically inject into the testscript before running it through our CI pipeline.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Our tests are step-based. Login is just an example. Also user-roles are not available in TestCafe Studio and therefore of no use.

Comment: @htho There is no supported way to execute previous tests in TestCafe Studio. I'd suggest looking into [Helper Methods](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/best-practices/create-helpers.html) which can be injected into TestCafe Studio via [Run TestCafe Scripts](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts#run-testcafe-script), although they would require extracting reused code from tests.